# JIRA content pack bringing only few rows on Power BI

Tags: jira, powerbi, jira-rest-api, powerbi-datasource

I was running the JIRA content pack (https://powerbi.microsoft.com/en-us/blog/explore-your-jira-data-with-power-bi/) on Power BI without any problems until today. But now I'm facing a issue that I cannot fix.

The problem is, suddenly the template started to limit the rows that are loaded from REST API. I didn't changed anything before this and I also checked if my JIRA user had some permission edition. Anybody knows what could be happening?

Thank you very much!

Answer (score -1):

I had the same problem, modify the number of results per page before it loops in the advanced editor: Source = FetchPages("", 100),

Comment: Generally you should try to avoid a one-liner answer by taking the time to explain how your solution helps.